# Where to Execute? SSRS OR SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When I'm creating an SSRS report, I always have a dilemma about "how to create the report with the least generation time possible".

In general the generation time (or performance time) is divided into two main parts:

1. The SQL Query.
2. The Report components (expressions, groups etc.).

As you know some of the things that are being performed in SSRS can be done in the SQL query and vice versa.

For example:

- I can use `Group by` clause in SQL, but can do the same when using a Table with Groups definition.
- I can use `Casting` in order to compare two values in SQL and also directly inside an expression.

and many more...

My questions are:

**A.** Which part (SQL query or SSRS) costs more time (assuming that the task can be made in both SSRS and SQL) ?

**B.** What are the guidelines, if any, on which I should base a decision when having a dillema where to execute the given situation?

Comment: +1 Quite an open ended question but definitely good one!

Comment: I vote up to both of you, cause truly i'm still confused :S

Comment: I thought about asking this question many times before, because this is truly an everyday situation that I deal with.

Answer (score 6):

As always with performance issues:

- **Don't prematurely optimize.** If something's simpler in SSRS then do it there. Only when a problem arises consider trading clarity for performance (possibly by moving code to the SQL side).
- **Measure.** Use the [ExecutionLog2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/05/executionlog2-view.aspx) view to get a general idea about where your bottle-necks are. Do more measuring and testing so you're sure you're investing time in improving performance of bits that matter.

**Bottom line**: let clarity of code guide where you solve a particular problem, and optimize selectively when performance becomes an issue.

---

Eric Lippert wrote [a nice blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) about when and how to worry about performance. The context is C#, but the basic idea holds for other situations such as SSRS/SQL as well.

By the way, if you have a look at mentioned [ExecutionLog2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/05/executionlog2-view.aspx) view, you'll notice that there's in fact *three* components in performance you should know about:

1. Data retrieval (SQL)
2. Report model (transforming the dataset to an internal model)
3. Rendering (transforming the model into an XLS, PDF, etc)

Knowing in which part a bottle-neck lies is key to knowing how to solve a performance problem.

---

To end with a suggestion based on my experience:

As a rule of thumb, **prefer SQL over SSRS** *if* you're worried about performance, especially for aggregation. Also consider tuning your database (indexes and such) if needed.

This rule of thumb would be best if I could back it up by facts and research. Alas, I don't have any. I *can* say that in my own experience, most often when I had performance problems with reports moving aggregation and calculation from SSRS to SQL would help in solving this issue.

Comment: It's confusing because you suggest just the opposite of @glh

Comment: My rule of thumb is indeed the opposite of @glh's advice. However, my *answer* is about a whole different aspect: if (and *only* if) you have a performance dilemma you should *measure*, and decide what's best for that scenario. I've restructured my answer to reflect that the rule of thumb is merely a footnote.

Comment: Number 1 don't prematurely optimise. The system is smarter than you. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is important to remember that SSRS is smart and saves exception until you need it. If you are exporting then it will extract all data. Also if you are viewing on line and you have expand and collapse rows they will not be executed until you want to view it. On that theory a basic SQL is preferred.

It would be best to leave the aggregation to SSRS as the report will attempt to aggregate in any case in the tablix. As for charts it's best to aggregate unless you have a tablix as well.

As for simple calculations this should be done in the SQL, such as comparisons, etc.

Remember that SSRS is *smarter* than you ;) and the simplest SQL enables this service to work best and this service is primarily for display.

If you use a MS SQL server for the dataset the service will work at its best.

Comment: It's confusing because you suggest just the opposite of @Jeroen

Comment: As per @Jeroen don't prematurely optimise and think of the service as two steps. 1. Getting  the data and 2. Formatting the report.  And remember that formatting the report can double up on SQL effort such as grouping and summing, etc.